# how to work with jprogress bar in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jprogressbar

i have a desktop GUI in swing , i want to show status of user storage used in the GUI using jProgressBar, Please suggest some attractive way to do.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: The tutorial ***is*** available, and you'd do well to read it.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) tutorial. I think it is the most attractive way to learn how to use JProgressBar.

To elaborate the answer a little:

```
JProgressBar progress = new JProgressBar(0, totalAvailableStorage);
progress.setValue(occupiedStorage);
```

Of course, you have to add the progress bar to its container and call progress.setValue() whenever needed.